# windows git - fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: USER

Tags: git, ssh

first off: I'm well aware that stackoverflow / the internet is full of similiar questions about this problem - but none had the answer to this specific one, even though I tried everything I could imagine in this case.

So, the problem is that I can't clone,pull,push,whatever to my remotely hosted repository on our Ubuntu server, when using git-bash or git.exe from my windows client. 
The exact error message is:

> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: pr_d

pr_developer is actually the user name, which I use for ssh login. 
So the problem is that the server responds with the username in the beginning, instead of what should be the message size (I read that is what git expects). But a test with ssh git-receive-pack was successful!
[image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKfMK.png)

```
$ git clone pr_developer@xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxx/git/delphi/ c:/workspace/test1234
Cloning into 'c:/workspace/test1234'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: pr_d

$ ssh pr_developer@xx.xx.xx.xx git-receive-pack /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxx/git/delphi/
00888c1bc7a0081e88bef034efb47ad6f7b14f3ce07e refs/heads/master report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet ofs-delta agent=git/1.9.1
0000Killed by signal 2.
```

The next thing I've tried is changing the shell of pr_developer. Neither /bin/bash nor /usr/bin/git-shell did solve it - the only difference is you can't login interactively with the git shell anymore.

The pr_developer user has no .bashrc that outputs something extra! When I log in with that user, it normally displays the "Welcome to Ubuntu"-Message, then leaves me with the cursor at `pr_developer@servername:~$` 
Well that "Welcome to Ubuntu" obviously doesn't seem to bother git, but the outprint of the username does, am I right?

---

Kenster, actually brought me to the idea of disabling TTY for the user. I've tried this by adding the following lines to my sshd_config, restarting and trying to clone again

```
Match User pr_developer
    PermitTTY no
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help!

Anyone knows what to do? Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please don't post your command as a screenshot, copy and past it in your question and format it with crtl + k as code. It will be easier for us to help you :-)

Comment: Have you tried to use another user to clone the repository?

Comment: Yes, in fact I can clone this repository with JetBrains PhpStorm (ssh login works just fine there...). But I think it works there because they use their own java implementation of git. Now I want to use git with Borland / Embarcadero Delphi and have to link to the git executable. It doesn't work there, with the same error as if I try to clone it manually via git-bash.

Comment: Are you forcing a tty on your ssh sessions? Could you [edit] your question to include your ssh client configuration?

Comment: Hello @Kenster no, I'm not forcing a tty on my ssh sessions. What do you want to know specificly about my ssh client configuration? 
The example I've made was just a simple ssh connection over command line (ssh client that comes with git / unix tools). I haven't used putty in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this behavior was caused by the `GIT_SSH` environment variable. It was set to:
 `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`
The solution was simply to delete the environment variable:
 `set GIT_SSH=`